# ThreeJS BoxHelper scale Not working

Tags: three.js

```
var sphere = new THREE.BoxGeometry(6,20,6);
var object = new THREE.Mesh( sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( 0xff0000 ));
var box = new THREE.BoxHelper( object, 0xffff00 );
var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(box.scale,'x',0,50).name('Width').listen();
```

the datgui shows the slider for box scale but changing it does not have any effect.Please help.

Comment: **1)** I have edited your post with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please consider including one with your question whenever you can. **2)** Please show what you have tried so far to fix the problem. If we suggest something that you have already tried that didn't work, it is a waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to set the `color` property ot the  [`THREE.MeshBasicMaterial`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48168712/threejs-boxhelper-scale-not-working):

```
var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(6,20,6);
var object = new THREE.Mesh( boxGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color:0xff0000} ));
```

Then you have to add the [`THREE.BoxHelper`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/helpers/BoxHelper) to the scene:

```
var box = new THREE.BoxHelper( object, 0xffff00 );
scene.add(boxHelper);
```

Further you have to change the `scale` property of the [`THREE.Mesh`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Mesh) and not the `scale` property of the `THREE.BoxHelper`. But you have to update (`onUpdate`) the `THREE.BoxHelper`:

```
var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(object.scale,'x',0.1,5).name('Width').onChange(function(){
    boxHelper.update(); 
} );
```

See the code snippet:

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var container, loader, camera, scene, renderer, controls, boxHelper;
  
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.set(15, -20, 15);

    loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin("");

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    scene.add(camera);
    window.onresize = resize;
    
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  
    var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(6,20,6);
    var object = new THREE.Mesh( boxGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color:0xff0000} ));
    
    scene.add(object);

    boxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper( object,  0x000000 );
    scene.add(boxHelper);

    var gui = new dat.GUI();
    gui.add(object.scale,'x',0.1,5).name('Width').onChange(function(){
      boxHelper.update(); 
    } );
  }

  function resize() {
    
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<!--script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/89/three.min.js"></script-->
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.6.5/dat.gui.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```